# flutter: force listview.builder fill all free space

Tags: flutter, listview

i tried to force listview.builder fill all free space (make scrollable to all free space) in screen
my code :

```
                     Column(
                     children:[
                     widget,
                     widget,
                     SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: medOrganizations.length,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 0, 35, 0),
                                itemBuilder:
                                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () async {
                                          appointmentModel.clinicOid =
                                              medOrganizations[index].id!;
                                          var medSpec =
                                              await _appointmentService
                                                  .getSpecialities(
                                                      appointmentModel
                                                          .cityId!,
                                                      appointmentModel
                                                          .clinicOid!);
                                          if (medSpec.statusCode == 200) {
                                            medSpecialities =
                                                medSpec.result!;
                                            stage = 2;
                                            selectClinic = false;
                                            selectSpecialist = true;
                                            clinic =
                                                "${medOrganizations[index].nameFull}";
                                            setState(() {});
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "${medOrganizations[index].nameFull}",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 20
                                                      .resizeFont(context)),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 5,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                                "${medOrganizations[index].nameShort}, ${medOrganizations[index].adress}",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 18.resizeFont(
                                                        context))),
                                            Divider(),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ));
                                },
                              ),
                            )])
```

this example, works but it doesn't fill all screen. I tried use Flex and Expanded, but always receive an error : "Error: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `column` has not `scrollable` parent widget. Then you can use `Expanded`. Which can take all free space of the screen.
Try this code:

```
Column(
                children:[
                  widget,
                  widget,
                  Expanded( <---------------------  remove sized box and wrap with expanded
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: medOrganizations.length,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 0, 35, 0),
                      itemBuilder:
                          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () async {
                                appointmentModel.clinicOid =
                                medOrganizations[index].id!;
                                var medSpec =
                                await _appointmentService
                                    .getSpecialities(
                                    appointmentModel
                                        .cityId!,
                                    appointmentModel
                                        .clinicOid!);
                                if (medSpec.statusCode == 200) {
                                  medSpecialities =
                                  medSpec.result!;
                                  stage = 2;
                                  selectClinic = false;
                                  selectSpecialist = true;
                                  clinic =
                                  "${medOrganizations[index].nameFull}";
                                  setState(() {});
                                }
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "${medOrganizations[index].nameFull}",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight:
                                        FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 20
                                            .resizeFont(context)),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                      "${medOrganizations[index].nameShort}, ${medOrganizations[index].adress}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.resizeFont(
                                              context))),
                                  Divider(),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                    ),
                  )])
```

Comment: I already tried , this. I receive an error "Error: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded"

Comment: Could it be , because of Visibility() widget? Cause my column in Visibility() widget

Comment: what is the parent widget of the `Column`

Comment: thi is my fault, i didn't describe full tree,
it seems like 
Column
 Visibility
   Column

Comment: what are other two `column`'s "widget".

Comment: thanks for help, i fully rewrited my widget according to your answers , it works  thanks for help